# if checkbox is checked show div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="yes" class="tick2">
```

and i am trying to use jquery to try and display div id '#content_more' when the checkbox is ticked and if it is unticked to re-hide the div.

i am using this and i am not able to get it to work, can anyone please show me where i am going wrong, thanks

```
<script>
$('.tick2').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#content_more").show();
    }
}); 
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="content_more">hello</div>
```

css:

```
#content_more{
width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
margin-top:50px;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
background-color: white;
padding: 9px 11px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom:60px;
dipslay:none;
```

Comment: I think you should use use id `terms` instead of class  like `$('terms').click(`

Comment: You need to wrap your script in `$(document).ready`, also there is nothing in your script to hide the div back. You also typed `display` wrong in your CSS.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact HTML structure? I posted an answer below that just uses CSS to accomplish this, but requires certain element paths. I can update my examples if you add more detail :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the structure of your HTML, you can accomplish this without a single line of JavaScript using the `:checked` CSS pseudo selector - given your CSS and content, here are a few examples:

**HTML Scenario 1** - immediately adjacent element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
<div class="content_more">hello</div>
```

CSS solution:

```
#terms:checked + .content_more {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML Scenario 2** - non-adjacent sibling:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div class="content_more">hello</div>
```

CSS solution:

```
#terms:checked ~ .content_more {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML Scenario 3** - target nested within non-adjacent sibling:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<section>
  <div class="content_more">hello</div>
</section>
```

CSS solution:

```
#terms:checked ~ section .content_more {
  display: block;
}
```

This solution depends on your HTML structure - if you provide a bit more in your question, I could be more specific with the CSS examples above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event (to recognise non-mouse interactions such as the user using their keyboard), and then use the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) function:

```
$('.tick2').change(function(e) {
    $('#content_more').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P75Tq/)

Note that if your `<script>` tag comes before the actual HTML to create the elements then the jQuery will execute before there are any elements to select, and therefore not bind any event handlers. To resolve that you'll need to use a DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tick2').change(function (e) {
        $('#content_more').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but this doesnt seem to be working, does this still work if the css display is set to none? and is the script ok in the header or does it need to go elsewhere on the page?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Edited my answer to address the effect of script location in relation to the elements themselves. If the script is before the elements HTML you'll need a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tick2').click(function() {
   $(".content_more").toggle("hide");
 });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/x5r98/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to class in your jQuery selector and fix the display typo in your CSS.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tick2').click(function () {
        $(".content_more").toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
    // ...
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    display:none;  // typo here in your code
}
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWGrp/)